# Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem

Tags: spacing, lists, theorems

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
On the other hand, this one has only one claim.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First claim
\item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Typesetting it results in:

[image]

Notice there is extra horizontal space before the first item in the list of the second theorem.

> Is there a sensible way to get rid of that?

Ideally, the solution would work with `amsthm`, `thmtools`, `enumitem`.

*N.B.:* this is related to [Is it possible to skip the first line in a theorem environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8110/525) but not quite the same.

Comment: @Martin: the plus signs meant something different than your commas :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw that. The main edit was the formatting of the package name with back-ticks `\``. Feel free to put the `+`s back in.

Answer (score 8):

Two variants of a solution using the `enumitem` package. In the first case, two `enumerate` environments were used; the first one uses leftamargin=* to suppress the undesired horizontal space; the second `enumerate` uses `resume` to keep the numbering but preserves the standard value for `\leftmargin`; the vertical spacing between the two environments was also corrected. In the second case, the option `leftmargin=*` was also used, but this time only one `enumerate` environment was used so the horizontal space will be removed for all the items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
   On the other hand, this one has only one claim.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item First claim
  \end{enumerate}\vspace*{-2\partopsep}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Second claim
  \end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
   On the other hand, this one has only one claim.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item First claim
    \item Second claim
  \end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `\@labels` trick (as in [Phil Hirschhorn's answer to “Avoiding a line break at the beginning of an enumerate”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/avoiding-a-line-break-at-the-beginning-of-an-enumerate/17134#17134)). Here's the result:

[image: Image of the result of the code]

There are two ways you can use this. The first is by manually putting a `\thmenumhspace` after `\begin{enumerate}` inside a theorem:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsthm,enumitem,thmtools}% works with or without
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\@thlabel@width}%
\newcommand{\thmenumhspace}{\settowidth{\@thlabel@width}{\itshape1.}\sbox{\@labels}{\unhbox\@labels\hspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\labelsep+\@thlabel@width-\itemindent}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
1. First claim 2. Second claim.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
\begin{enumerate}\thmenumhspace
\item First claim
\item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

With a little more work, this can be automated, hopefully without any side effects (this time, you need amsthm for it to work correctly):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,enumitem,thmtools}% needs amsthm
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thmenumhspace}[1]{\sbox{\@labels}{\unhbox\@labels\hskip#1}}
\let\original@item\item
\newlength{\@thlabel@width}%
\newcommand{\RedefineItem}{%
  \settowidth{\@thlabel@width}{\itshape1.}%
  \def\item{\let\item\original@item\thmenumhspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\labelsep+\@thlabel@width-\itemindent}\original@item}
}
\let\original@Theorem\Theorem
\def\Theorem{
   \@ifnextchar[{\Theorem@Opt}
                {\Theorem@NoOpt}
}
\def\Theorem@Opt[#1]{%
   \@ifnextchar\begin{\RedefineItem\original@Theorem[#1]}%
                     {\original@Theorem[#1]}%
}
\def\Theorem@NoOpt{%
   \@ifnextchar\begin{\RedefineItem\original@Theorem}%
                     {\original@Theorem}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
1. First claim. 2. Second claim.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First claim
  \item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
This one has two claims.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First claim
  \item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}[Title]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First claim
  \item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}[Title]
This one has two claims.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First claim
  \item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From where comes the dimension `-1em`? To me it is not enough. How to determine the exactly value to use to have the same output as with no `enumerate`?

Comment: @Sigur: I've edited the answer; it should now have the exact right amount of space whatever the settings are.

Comment: I saw that you edited only the automated code. But I'm using the simplest one since I'm using it only once. I tried the same value as `\baselineskip` (in my case, `1.5em`) and it looks right but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Sigur: I've also adapted the manual code. The exact value cannot be `1.5em`: it depends on the leftmargin, labelsep, itemindent and the size of the enumerate label.

Comment: Nice! Since I'm using the label style `(i)` and so on in upright font, should I use `\upshape(i)` instead of `\itshape1.`?

Comment: Hum, I've tested and it does not work with `[label=\textup{(\roman*)}]` from `enumitem` package.

Comment: @Sigur: if I replace `\itshape1.` by `\textup{(i)}` in the definition of `\thmenumhspace` and then use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\roman*)}]\thmenumhspace`, there's no spacing problem.

Comment: Ow, sorry. I hadn't seen that you had replaced *before each* by *after*. Now it works well. Thanks so much.

Comment: It does not work well with `a0poster`. I think that some font sizes or dimensions are affecting the computations. Any idea?

Comment: @Sigur: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I change the document class to `a0poster` in the two codes I gave above, everything looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for attention. I believe that problems come from `[label=\textup{(\arabic*)}]` option I'm using. I tried also to fix this in the `\thmenumhspace` definition but no progress.  Also in the second item its label `(2)` is to much on left.

Comment: @Sigur: for the first problem, try changing the beginning of `\thmenumhspace` to `\settowidth{\@thlabel@width}{\textup{(1)}}`; for the second problem, try using `[label=\textup{(\arabic*)},leftmargin=2em]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can hack a bit the first `\item` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand*\fixitem {\item[]%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}\hskip-\leftmargin\labelenumi\hskip\labelsep}
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
On the other hand, this one has only one claim.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
\fixitem First claim
\item Second claim
\end{enumerate}
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image: result of tex run]

Answer (score 1):

I found this trick that might help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}
On the other hand, this one has only one claim.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}    
\item[(i)] item one.    
\item[(ii)] item two.    
\item[(iii)]  item three.    
\end{itemize}
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is mentioned in the question I linked to, but does not do what I want because it starts a new line. I would like the list to start right beside the **Theorem 2**, but without the unnecessary space.

Comment: How is it unnessary? That is the default space between items in a list, that has nothing to do with theorems. If you whant to be able to configure this, see the `enumitem` package

Comment: @daleif: well, *I* consider it unnecessary to add extra horizontal space between the end of the **Theorem 2** text and the label of the first item in the list: it is inb that way that it is unnecessary! Also «see the `enumitem` package» does in no way help me... I *have* already seen it —I have been using for years now…— and I would not be asking if I knew how to achieve the effect I want to achieve. If you read the other answers, you'll notice that it is quite not a matter of using the `please-mariano` option to `enumitem`, too.

Comment: @mariano ahh, then I misunderstood, I was thinking vertical

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-answer whose purpose is to point out that some of the profered answers really gives correct marginal indentation of the enumerate items within a theorem.

Although I show the source and output from just one of the answers' methods,others give similar, undesirable indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}% works with or without

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  This is normal enumeration inside a theorem, which should be matched when no text precedes the enumeration:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \sometext
    \item \sometext
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{theorem}

Margination of the first item of next theorem does \emph{not} agree with the ``normal'' margination of the preceding Theorem 1.

\begin{theorem}\label{thm-2}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item \sometext
  \end{enumerate}\vspace*{-2\partopsep}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item \sometext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}


Margination of \emph{neither} item of the next theorem agrees with the ``normal'' margination of Theorem 1.

\begin{theorem}
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item \sometext
    \item \sometext
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

A theorem with no enumeration inside:

\begin{theorem}
   \sometext
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Now look at the items' indentation in the output, where the theorems that start directly with an enumerate do not have the same indentation as for a theorem that has text before the enumerate:

[image: Wrong indentation when enumerate immediately follows theorem heading]

**The question becomes:** When an `enumerate` immediate follows `\begin{theorem}`, ss there some way of:

- eliminating the extra horizontal space between "Theorem" and the number of the first item; and yet
- keep the same "normal" indentation of items as in a Theorem having some text before the `enumerate`?

avoiding the extra horizontal space between "Theorem" and the number of the first item

Comment: However, the `@label` trick *does* work -- even for theorem-like environments created using `thmtools` and for enumeration lists within them created using `enumitem`.