# How to change the (horizontal) distance between "Proof" and the first enumeration symbol?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, amsthm

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}
    Rhabarber Rhabarber Rhabarber Rhabarber
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Rhabarber Rhabarber
        \item Rhabarber Rhabarber
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theo}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Rhabarber Rhabarber
        \item Rhabarber Rhabarber
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Proof_vs_Enumeration]

The distance between "Proof." and "1. Rharbarber..." (marked with a red rectangle) is too great for my liking. How can I shorten it?

Comment: i'm sure this has been addressed before, but i haven't time to search.  i know there's an answer in the `amsthm` documentation -- `texdoc amsthm` (you must have a fairly recent installation of tex live; documentation was updated in april 2015).  the answer is on p.5, and although it is presented with respect to theorems, the same approach should work with a proof.

Comment: There is also the first related question (see above right on this page).

Comment: I found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/annoying-space-before-the-first-item-in-an-enumeration-which-starts-a-theorem) an appropriate answer. Thanks anyway!