# Removing horizontal space in enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate, amsart

> How can I remove the space between 1.1. and (1)?

[image]

**Edit:** @barbarabeeton's answer removes the space as required but I had a follow up question of whether there is a way to indent "Remark" with the body of the paragraph (1). Basically to have "Nullam" right below "Remark"in the following image: [image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1cm,right=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[Theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{remark}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item ABC
    \item ABC
\end{enumerate}
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZvG5.png) ([code](https://pastebin.com/raw/f0zZpFcd))?

Comment: `remark` is a theorem-class object.  See this question: [Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17449)

Comment: @Werner Yes, the hack doesn't work for me. Since I label the list items and need to refer to them later.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did use [leftmargin=*] after seeing that answer but there is still that little space left which is annoying.

Comment: I'll have to test that, but I have a meeting shortly, so it won't be possible for several hours.  There's another approach, if you're willing to start the list on a new line: insert `\leavevmode` right after the `\begin{remark}`, or add a few words to provide some text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have come across that too but sadly that's not what I want. However, please take your time. I am in no rush.

Comment: A fragile solution is `[leftmargin=15pt]` which seems to look good to me. But change any font settings and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in something a little more simplistic. Setting your own list-like environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[Theorem]{Remark}

\newcounter{remarkitem}
\newenvironment{remarklist}{%
  \setcounter{remarkitem}{0}% Restart counter
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\item}{\par
    \refstepcounter{remarkitem}%
    \ifnum\value{remarkitem}=1
      \hspace*{-0.5ex}%
    \fi
    \mbox{(\theremarkitem)}%
    \nobreakspace
  }
}{%
  \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
See number~\ref{list:first} and~\ref{list:second}.
\begin{remark}
  \begin{remarklist}
    \item\label{list:first} \lipsum*[1]
    \item\label{list:second} \lipsum*[2]
  \end{remarklist}
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this still doesn't align the body of the paragraphs with "Remark". I would like to have "purus" right below "Remark" in your image.

Comment: @SahibaArora: So something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l8VL.png)?

Comment: Yes exactly. How do I get that?

Comment: @SahibaArora: I've updated my answer with that detail. Note that you won't be able to use a nested list here. But I guess one can update that if necessary. It depends on the format.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Just out of curiosity, is there a way the numbering in the list can be changed to roman/alpha-numeric? When I use the enumerate environment, I add the optional argument [label=(alph*)]. Can something similar be done here?

Comment: @SahibaArora: Yes. Use `\renewcommand{\theremarkitem}{\alph{remarkitem}}` somewhere after `\newcounter{remarkitem}`.

Comment: This question has showed up today: [Enumeration content alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548310).  It doesn't involve a theorem-class object, but the visual structure appears identical, and is achieved with available options of the `enumitem` package.  Is there anything useful there?