# Enumeration content alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \noindent
    Hello
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =*, label = \textbf{Problem \arabic*.}]
        \item Find the Th\'evenin equivalent with respect to this resistor. Use this result to determine the conditions under which $R_9$ absorbs \textit{maximal} power.
        \item Based on the results obtained in Problem 1, select the resistor so that $\eta$ is maximized with the following additional constraint:
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output (with annotations):
[image]

Is there a way to move the second line such that it is aligned with the enumeration? My objective is that whenever a new line is made, it is aligned with the enumeration labels instead of with the first line.

Edit: here is a hand sketch of what I want:
[image]

Comment: could you add a hand drawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: Ok, give me a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumitem`'s keys to modify the lengths in the `enumerate` environment. Also, especially if you want to use multiple such lists, you could define a new list type.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{calc}
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problems]{
    label=\textbf{Problem \arabic*.},
    labelwidth={\widthof{\textbf{Problem 0.}} + \labelsep},
    itemindent=\labelwidth,
    leftmargin=0pt,
}
\begin{document} 
    \noindent
    Hello
    \begin{problems}
        \item Find the Th\'evenin equivalent with respect to this resistor. Use this result to determine the conditions under which $R_9$ absorbs \textit{maximal} power.
        \item Based on the results obtained in Problem 1, select the resistor so that $\eta$ is maximized with the following additional constraint:
    \end{problems}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a nice solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: This earlier question requests the same visual result: [Removing horizontal space in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547855).  An important difference is that a theorem-class object is involved in the other question.  But it would be nice if a common approach could apply to both.