# Annoying space before first item in an enumeration that starts a theorem-like environment

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, indentation, theorems

In a theorem-like environment that begins with a (parenthesized) enumeration, how can the *horizontal* extra space before the item be eliminated but:

- *without* destroying correct indentation of the body of the items, including lines after the first one in an item; and
- *without* requiring *no* blank line before the body of the first item; and
- *without* unduly shrinking the space between the first item's label and its body text?

In the output from the source below, the first red arrow marks where the extra unwanted horizontal space appears.

As we can see in "1.3 Examples", the attempt to eliminate the extra horizontal space of the first item destroys the uniform horizontal indentation of the first item. In "1.4 Examples", the body of the first item begins a separate paragraph after its label. In "1.5 Examples", the latter issue is avoided by eliminating the blank line in the source, but there is too little space between the first item's label and its body text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\sometxt}{%
Some text begins this. The identity is $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$ %
and in very simple terms $(a + b)^2 \neq a^2 + b^2$.%
On the other hand, we do have the basic law of powers that $(a b)^2 = a^2 b^{2}$.
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,thmtools}

\newlist{pexenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pexenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*)}

\swapnumbers

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \bfseries, headpunct={\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{exstyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=exstyle, numberlike=theorem,
  ]
{examples}

\begin{document}

\section{The  section}

\noindent This is OK with text within the environment precedes the enumeration:

\begin{examples}
  Text before the enumeration.
    \begin{pexenum}
      \item 
      
      \sometxt      
      \setcounter{pexenumi}{9}
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\noindent \textbf{The problem}, when \emph{no} text precedes enumeration---too much horizontal space before 1st label:
\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}
      \item 
      
      \sometxt
      \setcounter{pexenumi}{9}
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\noindent  Attempted fix---\verb!leftmargin=*! etc.. \emph{Wrong}---entire 1st item exdented:

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17487/13492:
\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}[leftmargin=*]
      \item 
      
      \sometxt
    \end{pexenum}\vspace*{-2\partopsep}
    \begin{pexenum}[resume]
    \setcounter{pexenumi}{9}
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\noindent  Attempted fix---use \verb!\fixitem!.. \emph{Wrong}---1st item body begins new paragraph after item label:

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17500/13492:
\newcommand*\fixitem{\item[]%
  \refstepcounter{pexenumi}\hskip-\leftmargin\labelpexenumi\hskip0.5\labelsep}
  
\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}
      \fixitem % The blank line before the item's text is deliberate!
      
      \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
    \setcounter{pexenumi}{9}
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\noindent  Attempted fix---use \verb!\fixitem!.---no blank line. This works, but \emph{awkward} having to avoid the blank line:
  
\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}
      \fixitem 
%      
      \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
    \setcounter{pexenumi}{9}
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

[image: Spacing after label of 1st item in enumerate inside a theorem-like environment]

**Edit:** The `@label` method shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17465/13492 seems to work!

**Related:**

The question is similar to that of [Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/annoying-space-before-the-first-item-in-an-enumeration-which-starts-a-theorem/586852#586852), except that now:

- the enumeration is done with parenthesized numbers (which may affect spacing); and
- each item has more than one line, whereas in the original question each item had a single line which obscured the shortcoming in the answers provided there.

The source shows just one method that tries to remove the unwanted horizontal space before the first item, but the other methods given in answers to [Annoying space before the first item in an enumeration which starts a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17449/annoying-space-before-the-first-item-in-an-enumeration-which-starts-a-theorem/586852#586852) suffer the same shortcoming.

See also my "non-answer" https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586852/13492.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sometxt}{%
Some text begins this. The identity is $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$ %
and in very simple terms $(a + b)^2 \neq a^2 + b^2$.%
On the other hand, we do have the basic law of powers that $(a b)^2 = a^2 b^{2}$.
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,thmtools}

\newlist{pexenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pexenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*), wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}

\swapnumbers

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \bfseries, headpunct={\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{exstyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=exstyle, numberlike=theorem,
  ]
{examples}

\begin{document}

\section{The section}

\begin{examples}
  Text before the enumeration.
    \begin{pexenum}
      \item \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}
      \item \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}[leftmargin=*]
      \item \sometxt
    \end{pexenum}\vspace*{-2\partopsep}
    \begin{pexenum}[resume]
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: I you prefer right-aligned labels in lists, you can use the `widest` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\sometxt}{%
Some text begins this. The identity is $\sin²(θ) + \cos²(θ) = 1$ %
and in very simple terms $(a + b)² ≠ a² + b²$.%
On the other hand, we do have the basic law of powers that $(a b)² = a² b^{2}$.
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,thmtools}

\newlist{pexenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pexenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*), widest=99, leftmargin=*}

\swapnumbers

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \bfseries, headpunct={\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{exstyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=exstyle, numberlike=theorem,
  ]
{examples}

\begin{document}

\section{The section}

\begin{examples}
  Text before the enumeration.
    \begin{pexenum}[start=9]
      \item \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}
      \item \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}[leftmargin=*]
      \item \sometxt
    \end{pexenum}\vspace*{-2\partopsep}
    \begin{pexenum}[resume]
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: I slighly modified the code for the hack:

```
   \begin{examples}
        \begin{pexenum}
          \item[(1)\phantom{0}\kern0.05em\stepcounter{pexenumi}]\hskip-0.55em\sometxt
          \item \sometxt
       \end{pexenum}
    \end{example}
```

[image: enter image]

Comment: Unfortunately, NO! None of the numerical labels is properly indented so as to allow numbers higher than 9. In the first `\begin{enumerate}` add `\item hello\item hello\item hello\item hello\item hello\item hello\item hello\item\sometxt`. Then the numerical labels become left-aligned instead of the normal right-aligned; and the text of the first line of the 10th item is pushed rightwards away from alignment with all the other items' first lines (which is the same as the whole text of the other items).

Comment: I see better. What you want was not quite clear from your post. What  would be the maximum value of the labels?

Comment: for *my* purposes, the default maximum of 2 digits is OK.

Comment: @murray: So it's covered by the key used in my edit: `widest=99`.

Comment: Both 1.2 Esamples and 1.3 Examples still have the unwanted extra space between "Examples." and "(1)" that I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: @murray: this is due to the `widest=99` key that saves the necessary space for a two-digit counter and the right alignment of the counters. You can hack using the optional argument of \item, something like `\item[(1)\phantom{1}] \stepcounter{pexenumi}`.

Comment: And that "necessary space for a two-digit counter" and "right alignment" is precisely what I'm trying to get around in the situation of the first item within an enumerate that's inside another environment!

Comment: Did you try the dirty hack to see whether it produces more or less what you want?

Comment: which "dirty hack"?

Comment: What I mentioned in thhe last but one comment: use `\item[(1)\phantom{1}] \stepcounter{pexenumi}` for the first item.

Comment: Using `\item[(1)\phantom{1}] \stepcounter{pexenumi}` for the first item seems to introduce an extra amount of space between the "(1)" label and the text following it.

Comment: Strange… I'll check what can be done

Comment: Using \item[(1)\phantom{1}] \stepcounter{pexenumi} for the first item *also* suffers the limitation that unless you leave no blank line between that and the body text of the first item, that body text begins a new paragraph &mdash; unlike the normal situation with an `'\item`. (That's the same limitation as for answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586917/13492.)

Comment: You can incorporate `\stepcounter{pexenumi}`  to the optional argument of  the  `\item` command.

Comment: Using `\item[(1)\phantom{1}\stepcounter{pexenumi}]` takes care of the issue of a blank line preceding the text body of the first item. It still provides too little space between the label "(1)" and the first item's body text; that requires an additional hack, e.g.: `\item[(1)\phantom{1}\stepcounter{pexenumi}\hspace{-0.5em}]`.

Comment: Please make your hack, with my addendum of `\hspace{0.5em}` and answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Oops: I'm still getting the original, excessive space before "(1)" when using `\item[(1)\phantom{1}\stepcounter{pexenumi}`.

Comment: @murray: I've modified the hack. Please see if it corresponds more to what you want now.

Comment: The modified hack still has problem that, if there is a blank line between the `\item[{1)\phantom...` and the body of the item text, then the body text of the first item begins a new pargraph, on a new line of the output (instead of the normal behavior of an enumerate, where the body of the item immediately follows its label).

Comment: Why would you have a blank line between the item label and the body of the item?

Comment: I don't want a blank line between the item label and the body of the item. What I do want is, in the `.tex` source, to have a handy way, both for writing and reading: `\begin{examples}\label{blah-blah}`, blank line,  `\item\label[more-blah-blah}` blank line, body text of first item, blank line, etc.

Comment: If I understand what you want, it is only for the readability of the code?  In this case, replace your blank line with a line with  the single comment character (`%`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `first` key together with the tricks in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17500).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sometxt}{%
Some text begins this. The identity is $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$ %
and in very simple terms $(a + b)^2 \neq a^2 + b^2$.%
On the other hand, we do have the basic law of powers that $(a b)^2 = a^2 b^{2}$.
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,thmtools}

\newlist{pexenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pexenum,1]{label= \upshape(\arabic*)}

\swapnumbers

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \bfseries, headpunct={\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{exstyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=exstyle, numberlike=theorem,
  ]
{examples}

\newcommand*\myfirstitem{\item[]% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17500
  \refstepcounter{pexenumi}\hskip-\leftmargin\labelpexenumi\hskip0.5\labelsep
  \let\olditem\item
  \def\item{\let\item\olditem}%
  }


\begin{document}

\section{The  section}

\begin{examples}
  Text before the enumeration.
    \begin{pexenum}
      \item \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}[first=\myfirstitem]
      \item \sometxt
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\begin{examples}
    \begin{pexenum}[leftmargin=*]
      \item \sometxt
    \end{pexenum}\vspace*{-2\partopsep}
    \begin{pexenum}[resume]
      \item \sometxt
   \end{pexenum}
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work perfectly. *Limitation:* In case of multiple kinds of enumerate environments defied like that for `pexenum`, we would need corresponding separate versions of `myfirsstitem`. *Caution:* would need some change in (unlikely) situation of more than 99 items!

Comment: There is a defect in this `myfirst...` method: A blank line between the `\begin{pexenum}[first=\myfirstitem]` and the first `\item` causes the body of the first item to begin a new paragraph. Ordinarily, blank lines between a `\begin{enumerate}` and the first `\item` cause no such behavior.

Comment: @murray This may be but I am not a fan of accepting and unaccepting games, so I wish you good luck with your query.

Comment: Sorry, no bad intentions. I discovered the defect later on when I tried it on another document. (The underlying hack you referenced does work, though, even with the blank line before the first item.)

Comment: It does not matter, I quit anyway because of [these incidents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587649/237299). This site is not for me.